# What does call sleep(1) mean in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

```
      program democonstanta

      implicit none

c     constanta
      integer, parameter :: MIN_VALUE = 0
      integer, parameter :: MAX_VALUE = 100

c     var declaration
      integer :: i = MIN_VALUE      

      do while (i <=MAX_VALUE)
         write(*,'(a14)') "Please wait... "
         write(*,'(i3,a2)', advance='no') i, "%"
         call sleep(1)
         if (i .it. MAX_VALUE) then
            call execute_command_line("clear")
         end if
         i = i + 1
      end do

      call execute_command_line("clear")
      write(*,'(a3)') "End."

      end program democonstanta
```

Comment: It's for calling a subroutine named `sleep` with argument `1`.  There's nothing exotic about `sleep` compared with, say, `execute_command_line` except some compilers may offer it as an intrinsic and some don't.  That is: it isn't obvious to me what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SLEEP.html

It simply sleeps (waits) for a given number of seconds. In your case - one.